# what's the equivalence of Clang++'s "-rdynamic" option in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm, clang++, cmakelists-options

I'm trying to create a new programming language by reading LLVM documents. One of the documents is about "Kaleidoscope", a toy programming language. (tutorial's here: https://releases.llvm.org/9.0.0/docs/tutorial/LangImpl01.html).

All the codes in tutorial are written in a single file, and can be compiled by the command below:

```sh
clang++ -g -O3 toy.cpp -I/usr/lib/llvm-10/include -std=c++14  \
-fno-exceptions -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS \
-L/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib \
-rdynamic \
-lLLVM-10 -o toy
```

However, I want to manage my project by CMake. I've translate most of the command above into
a `CMakeLists.txt` file (attached afterwards), besides the option "-rdynamic".
Does anyone know how to add this option to my `CMakeLists.txt` ? Thanks in advance!

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang++")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/lib/llvm-10/include")
LINK_DIRECTORIES("/usr/lib/llvm-10/lib")

SET(_GNU_SOURCE 1)
SET(__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS 1)
SET(__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS 1)
SET(__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS 1)

# Project configuration
# omit something unrelated

FIND_PACKAGE(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(compiler LLVM-10)
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow we don't mark the question with "Closed" or "Solved" in the title. After you accept an answer, your question will be automatically marked as green. But even in that state it is perfectly allowed to add answers to the question, so they could be found by *future readers*.

Answer (score 5):

The clean way is to set the [ENABLE_EXPORTS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/ENABLE_EXPORTS.html) property:

```
set_property(TARGET compiler PROPERTY ENABLE_EXPORTS ON)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite akward to find out just adding this to `CMakeLists.txt` is OK.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -rdynamic)
```

Answer (score -1):

`-rdynamic` is a linker flag, so you should use [`target_link_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html) to add it to your target.

**Example**: `target_link_options(compiler PRIVATE rdynamic)`

If it were a compiler flag, you'd have to use [`target_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html)

On a smaller note, writing CMake commands in upper case is considered obsolete. The modern practice is to use lowercase commands: `set()`, `include_directories()` etc.